# Cause of WP8.1 release build exception: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found"?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

I'm posting a problem I recently encountered while developing a Windows Phone 8.1 release mode app.  Fortunately, I was able to solve the problem, which I would like to share via StackOverflow.

The problem encountered was as follows:

- I have a Windows Phone 8.1 (WP8.1) application which has a Windows Runtime Component.
- When compiled in debug mode, the application works perfectly.
- When I build it in release mode, the application links and runs. However, when the C# portion attempts to instantiate the Windows Runtime Component class, the app throws a System.IO.FileNotFoundException exception, caught by Application_UnhandledException() in App.xaml.cs:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
. . .
```

I attempted to debug the release version, disabling all optimizations in the project, but the results were not conclusive.  The breakpoint I placed on the native code constructor was never hit by the debugger (I switched debugging to "Native Only" in Properties>Debug).

Reviewing the compiler and linker settings did not show anything out of the ordinary.  What was the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the System.IO.FileNotFoundException being thrown was because the list of libraries to link in release mode (Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies) included SQLite3D.lib (the debug version of the SQLite library) rather than SQLite.lib (the release version):

> API.lib;Internals.lib;JSON.lib;sqlite3D.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

This was enough to prevent Windows Phone 8.1 from loading the Windows runtime component DLL to invoke the class constructor.

The solution was to link the release lib rather than the debug one:

> API.lib;Internals.lib;JSON.lib;sqlite3.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

This explains why the app works perfectly in debug mode.

My experience in C/C++ has taught me that mixing debug and release libs can be problematic.  An example is allocating memory in a release mode DLL and deallocating the memory in a debug mode DLL, because there are two different memory management systems at play here.  The case at hand illuminates another reason for not mixing release and debug DLLs/libraries.